# First Rifle with Scope

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I've always wanted to play a sniper in an RPG, and I've just started playing Fallout: New Vegas. This seems like a perfect fit. I'm pretty excited.

What is the earliest point in the game I can find/buy/make a scope for my gun?

Comment: Just to let you know, the PS3 tag is meant for questions about the console itself.  Just mentioning your platform in your question is sufficient

Comment: @sommerjj I didn't know that, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might actually be able to find a scope in stock in Goodsprings if you're lucky. Chet stocks the varmint rifle night scope mod on occasion, which you can use to add a scope to the varmint rifle that Sunny should have given to you.

If you don't have enough bottlecaps to purchase a scope mod, you can go looking for the Ratslayer, a unique varmint rifle that comes equipped with all the varmint rifle mods (scope included). The Broc Flower Cave can be found north of Camp Searchlight.

[image: Map]

There will be *many* giant rats there, so be cautious and prepared. It may not be very easy for a beginning character, but the Ratslayer is one of the best weapons for its "level".

Comment: I could get one right off the bat? Nice! I will check that out shortly. So... scopes are only made for certain guns? I can't make/buy a scope that will work on any gun? Strange.

Comment: Outside of third-party mods, weapon typically cannot be made/crafted, only purchased and, yes, each weapon mod is specific to a certain weapon (you can't add a varmint rifle scope or silencer to a hunting rifle, for example).

Comment: [Here's a list of locations for the varmit rifle night scope.](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Varmint_rifle_night_scope)  It's probably your best bet early.  Once you have 1300 caps, you could buy a hunting rifle scope.  Once you've played a while, you could look into a real sniper rifle.  [Locations are here](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Sniper_rifle_(Fallout:_New_Vegas)#Locations)